# Itunes has redircted half of my music when I unplugged my external hard drive - How do I move them back?

Tags: itunes

Itunes has redircted half of my music when I unplugged my external hard drive - How do I move them back?

I unplugged my external drive (F:) whilst my wife was downloading pictures off her camera (E:). Now iTunes has redirected over half my tracks to the E: drive. The only grace is that the music is still on the F: drive, but it has now lost the link. How do I make iTunes relink these tracks? I can't do it one by one as there's over 9,000. Please help!

Comment: So you were synchronizing your music with your external hard drive when you unplugged it, after which iTunes decided to put the music on your wifes camera instead?

Comment: iTunes was open at the time. iTunes defaulted back to the C: location to add the music, but half the music links went to the camera as I mentioned before. So half my music is linked to the F: drive, half to the E: and a few albums on the C: drive. All the music is still on the F:, I just need to know how I could reridect all the music back to the F: drive

Answer (score 1):

Could you delete all the links from the library and the re-add the songs?

Comment: How do I do that? I've already redirected the location in iTunes to the F: but all the songs that are located now on the E: drive won't changes back.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "redirect". iTunes has the option to move audio files to the library's storage location when they're being added to the library. Do you have this feature enabled? If so, set the library location, enable that preference (if it's not already enabled), delete either the entire library (not the files, just the links) or just the selected broken links, and then re-import your audio files. This will copy the files all to the right location. I hope that helps...I guess I'm not quite sure how best to answer your question because I'm not quite clear on the problem.